# PHP changing loaded page link style

Tags: php, css, styles

Is there any automatic way to change style of loaded page link? For example, here is my menu:

```
<a href="private.php?show=link1"><div class="side_cat_btn_grn">
    <div class="in_block side_btn_logo"><img src="img/ico/ico_id1.png" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="in_block side_btn_txt txtsdw_green">link1</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div></a>
<a href="private.php?show=link2"><div class="side_cat_btn_grn">
    <div class="in_block side_btn_logo"><img src="img/ico/ico_id2.png" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="in_block side_btn_txt txtsdw_green">link2</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div></a>
<a href="private.php?show=link3"><div class="side_cat_btn_grn">
    <div class="in_block side_btn_logo"><img src="img/ico/ico_id3.png" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="in_block side_btn_txt txtsdw_green">link3</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div></a>
<a href="private.php?show=link4"><div class="side_cat_btn_grn">
    <div class="in_block side_btn_logo"><img src="img/ico/ico_id4.png" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="in_block side_btn_txt txtsdw_green">link4</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div></a>
```

So question is, how to change loaded page **private.php?show=link1** style without attaching style in each page?
Coz i have lots of pages and whole menu is included from php file. So style would be changed depending from loaded page like: **private.php?show=link1** or **private.php?show=link3** would it be on PHP or some other way?

Cheers!

Comment: The best way is to apply the corresponding style in the PHP rendering. It can be done also with Javascript comparing the location.href with array of predefined URLs and styles, but this is really bad practice, I do not recommend it.

Comment: Well, that i won't use it this way :) But adding menu without including it from file to each page and selecting active style is also not an option :( More ideas? :)

Answer (score 1):

In your private.php you can put something like :

```
 switch ($_GET['show']) {
    case 'link1':
          echo "<style> .... </style>";
        break;
    case 'link2':
          echo "<style> .... </style>";
        break;
    case 'link3':
          echo "<style> .... </style>";
        break;
    case 'link4':
          echo "<style> .... </style>";
        break;

    default:
          echo "<style> .... </style>";
        break;
}
```

Replace the `...` with your CSS for each link.

Comment: Cheers! I did it bit different: <a class="<?php switch ($_GET['show']) { case 'mobile': echo "link_style_act"; break; default: echo "link_style_def"; break;} ?>" href="index.php?show=mobile">show mobile</a> :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascrpt to get value of link:

```
<script>
    function loadcontent(link){

        $('#mystyle').load('private.php?link='+link);

    }

</script>
```

so your link must be like this:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="loadcontent('yourlinknumber')"><div id='mystyle'></a>
```

and then in your php file do something like this:

```
 $link = $_GET['link'];
 //echo the divs you like depending on value of $link
```